# how to only edit and destroy my own content only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Have a basic blog (it's actually edgeguide's blog: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Then I integrated Devise into it. So, user can only log in and see their own information.

Now trying to change it somewhat.

I'd like the users to see all content, but **only edit and destroy** their own only.

Trying to use `before_action` filter like this:

```
 `before_action :authorize, :only => [:edit, :destroy]`
```

And this is the authorize method that I wrote:

```
     def authorize
       @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        if !@article.user_id = current_user.id then 
        flash[:notice] = "You are not the creator of this article, therefore you're not permitted to edit or destroy this article"
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work. Everything acts as normal, and I can delete mine and everyone's else content.

How do I get it that I can destroy ONLY my own content, and not everyone's else?

Not using CanCan, nor do I want to.

Not sure if this is worth including or not, but originally when I had everyone see their own content, that was via create action:

```
   def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    if @article.save

        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having several problems

first, look at that :

```
if !@article.user_id = current_user.id then
```

You're only using one `=` instead of `==` so you are doing an assignation that will evaluate to `current_user.id`

Also, in your condition, you're only setting a flash message but not doing anything to really prevent the user.

Here's a corrected version :

```
def authorize
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  unless @article.user_id == current_user.id 
    flash[:notice] = "You are not the creator of this article, therefore you're not permitted to edit or destroy this article"
    redirect_to root_path # or anything you prefer
    return false # Important to let rails know that the controller should not be executed
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks! (additional fluff characters here as comments are required to be 15 characters in length, huh!)